# Set focus on p-inputNumber

Tags: angular, typescript, focus, primeng, autofocus

I open a `p-dialog` with a `p-inputNumber` inside, but I don't manage to set focus on it.

I tried to put autofocus, as you see, but it doesn't work. The focus remains on the button I pressed to open the dialog. How can I do? Thanks.

```
<p-dialog header="Title" [(visible)]="displayModal" [modal]="true" [style]="{width: '40vw'}"
  [baseZIndex]="10000" [draggable]="false" [resizable]="false" [closable]="false">
  <p class="p-m-0">
    <p-inputNumber size=3 [(ngModel)]="field" maxlength="3" autofocus></p-inputNumber>
  </p>
  <ng-template pTemplate="footer">
    <button >Ok</button>
  </ng-template>
</p-dialog>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add a reference to your input in order to manipulate it from typescript via a `ViewChild`:

```
<p-inputNumber size=3 [(ngModel)]="field" maxlength="3" #input></p-inputNumber>
```

and

```
@ViewChild("input") elm;
```

Then, set the focus to this input once the dialog shows up by using `onShow` method:

```
(onShow)="setFocus()"
```

and

```
setFocus() {
    this.elm.input.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

See [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dialog-demo-omnfcr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Antikhippe can you help me again? In the previous example, If I want to launch a function when I press Enter, what I have to do?

Comment: You can use `onInput` event according to [PrimeNG doc](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/inputnumber) to do that.

Comment: onInput is only fired when I type numbers, but not when I press Enter

Comment: You're right. You can use `keypress` event instead.